# Is it possible to build an Apex Trigger to check if a long text area field contains a certain string?

Tags: apex

I have a long text area field on the contact object called Lead_History_Text_2__c. I need to be able to pull from this field every time it's updated if it contains certain strings of text. For example, if Lead History Text 2 contains "Demo_CQG", then it needs to update a date field on the Contact object. Is something like this possible with Apex? I think this is the most elegant solution for my problem, I'd like to try to avoid jumping through hoops and making multiple fields just to extract some info from one field. If this is more easily achievable another way then feel free to let me know, this is just the first thing I thought of.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a LongTextArea field type is a `String`, and the [String class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm) provides a `.contains()` method (along with many others) which does what you're looking to do.

Be aware that `.contains()` is case-sensitive

In normal circumstances, I'd advocate for using a before-save record-triggered flow or using the WHERE clause of a query to do your filtering. When you're working with LongTextArea fields though, those options aren't available.

Comment: N.B. `containsIgnoreCase` can be used for case insensitive logic